# Globbing for double extension files

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob, node-glob

I have this Gulp snippet:

```
gulp.src(['./assets/**/*.!(coffee|scss)', '!assets/images{,/**}'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/public'))
```

And this folder structure:

- assets

  - js

    - A.coffee
    - A.B.coffee
    - A.B.C.coffee
    - X.js

The intention is to copy everything except:

- the contents of assets/images
- any and all CoffeeScript files

However, this glob pattern does not exclude A.B and A.B.C.coffee.

What is the correct pattern to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Try this

```
gulp.src(['./assets/**/!(*.coffee|*.scss)', '!assets/images'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/public'))
```